# How to ask a useful question?

Tags: discussion

I always wonder how to ask a useful question? the question should be useful to both readers and answer providers?

what are the characteristics of a good question

Comment: See also: [An easy guide to earning downvotes](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/an-easy-guide-to-earning-downovtes/1703#1703)

Answer (score 2):

Peter Kreeft, a professor of philosophy and theology at Boston College, is fond of saying how much harder good questions are, and how much more important a process that is.

It is probably good to start by looking at how to avoid asking a bad question. I would check out the [help section](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), since it covers it pretty well.

Comment: is he right? what sort of context is he talking about, and for whom is it easier?